# Read one column values from database and and sort randomly and put the sorted values into other column

Tags: vbscript

I have a requirement to read one complete column values from Access database and need to sort it in a random order/ Descending order and update the sorted values to another column so , that one name is assigned to another name. That to only using VB script.

I know only how to read the values from Access database i don't know further steps..

Could any one help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

One Recordset sort Desc, second Recordset sort Asc. Then loop through the first RS and update the table with the first RS value where table value equals second RS value.
In this example change ColumnName, ColumnName2 and TableName according to your database. ColumnName2 is output column so it will be replaced with new values.

```
Sub AddDescToAsc()

Dim MyDB As DAO.Database, MyRS As DAO.Recordset, MyRS2 As DAO.Recordset

Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
Set MyRS = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName ORDER BY ColumnName DESC",     dbOpenForwardOnly)
Set MyRS2 = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName ORDER BY ColumnName ASC")
MyRS2.MoveFirst
With MyRS
    Do While Not .EOF
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName2 = '" & .Fields("ColumnName") & "' WHERE     ColumnName = '" & MyRS2(0) & "'"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        MyRS2.MoveNext
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

MyRS.Close
MyRS2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, i was able to sort the data in descending order and i could update the other column with the sorted data. 
Is there any ways to update the 2nd column with the random data of 1st coulmn??

Comment: If there is any other column then the 1 and 2, you can sort by that column to get random order.

Comment: My table has some 7 columns, i need to update the 7th column with the Random value of 1st column.

Comment: To get random order of column1 change the first select statement to sort by any other column (lets call the other column _ColumnNameX_). The _ColumnNameX_ must have some data. __"SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName ORDER BY ColumnNameX DESC"__ The sorted order of ColumnNameX is probably random to order of Column1.